# Makefile: Expand relative PREFIX path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my Makefile, there is a `PREFIX` variable for specifying where the finished files should be placed. However, internally, I need to use the absolute path of `PREFIX` because the working directory changes.

I tried something like

```
PREFIX=../out
REALPREFIX=`readlink -f $(PREFIX)`
```

which didn't work, and neither did

```
default: fixprefix $(addprefix $(REALPREFIX)/,$(OBJS))

fixprefix:
        REALPREFIX=`readlink -f $(PREFIX)`
```

All I need is for the absolute path to be prefixed onto `OBJS` when the prerequisites list is calculated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're using GNUMake, you can do this:

```
REALPREFIX = $(realpath $(PREFIX))
```

Comment: Thanks. Wondering why the original command used by the OP doesn't work?

Comment: @Tim: It depends on what backticks do in that shell, and whether `$(PREFIX)` was a symbolic link. "Didn't work" isn't very informative.

Comment: NB if the path you want to expand doesn't exist yet, you can use `$(abspath $(PATH))`